# convert dataframe to a nested dictionary without column names

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

This is a sample of my pandas dataframe and it contains close to 100k rows

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': ['5', '5', '5', '5', '5', '5'],
         'mdse_item_i': ['23627102',
                         '23627102',
                         '23627102',
                         '23627102',
                         '23627102',
                         '23627102'],
         'predPriceQty': ['35.675543',
                         '33.236678',
                         '35.675543',
                         '35.675543',
                         '35.675543',
                         '35.675543'],
         'schedule_i': ['56', '56', '56', '56', '56', '56'],
         'segment_id': ['4123', '4123', '4144', '4161', '4295', '4454'],
         'wk': ['1', '2', '1', '1', '1', '1']} )
```

| segment_id | cluster | schedule_i | mdse_item_i | wk | predPriceQty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4123 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 1 | 35.675543 |
| 4123 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 2 | 33.236678 |
| 4144 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 1 | 35.675543 |
| 4161 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 1 | 35.675543 |
| 4295 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 1 | 35.675543 |
| 4454 | 5 | 56 | 23627102 | 1 | 35.675543 |

Below is the nested format of the dictionary i'm looking to achieve

```py
{(4123, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1: 35.6755430505491, 2:33.236678}}},
 (4144, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1: 35.6755430505491}}},
 (4161, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1: 35.6755430505491}}},
 (4295, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1: 35.6755430505491}}},
 (4454, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1: 35.6755430505491}}}}
```

The code below works for me but for huge dataframes, it takes hours to create the dictionary and i'm trying to **avoid row-wise iteration**

```py
forecast_dict_all = {}
for _, row in df.iterrows():
        item_agg_id = int(row[segment_id])
        mdse_item_i = row["mdse_item_i"]
        cluster = int(row["cluster"])
        wk = int(row["wk"])
        forecast = float(row["predPriceQty"])
        schedule_id = row["schedule_i"]
        
        if (item_agg_id, cluster) not in forecast_dict_all:
            forecast_dict_all[item_agg_id, cluster] = {
                schedule_id: {mdse_item_i: {wk: forecast}}
            }
```

My solution so far

```
dict(df.groupby(['segment_id','cluster'],as_index=False).apply(lambda x: x.to_dict()).to_dict())
```

```
df.set_index(['segment_id', 'cluster'], inplace=True)
    
di = df.to_dict(orient='index')
    
forecast_dict_all = {k:{v['schedule_i']: {v['mdse_item_i']: {v['wk']: v['predPriceQty']}}} 
                            for k,v in di.items()}
```

```
df.set_index(['segment_id', 'cluster'], inplace=True)
{k:{grp['schedule_i']: {grp['mdse_item_i']: {grp['wk']: grp['predPriceQty']}}}
for k, grp in df.groupby(['schedule_i','mdse_item_i','wk','predPriceQty'])}
```

I even tried using zipping but in both the instances, i could not achieve the desired output.

Edit
I am using
python: 2.7.13.final.0
pandas: 0.20.1

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 3):

I have no idea whether this will be faster, but it gives the expected output with your example data.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df = df.astype(dtype={'cluster': int, 'mdse_item_i': int, 'predPriceQty': float,
                'schedule_i': int, 'segment_id': int, 'wk': int})
df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
df.set_index(['segment_id', 'cluster'], inplace=True)
answer = df.apply(lambda row:
                {row['schedule_i']: {row['mdse_item_i']: {row['wk']: row['predPriceQty']}}},
                axis=1).to_dict()
```

Result:

```
{(4123, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1.0: 35.675543}}},
 (4144, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1.0: 35.675543}}},
 (4161, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1.0: 35.675543}}},
 (4295, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1.0: 35.675543}}},
 (4454, 5): {56.0: {23627102.0: {1.0: 35.675543}}}}
```

**Note**: I fixed the dataframe's types because you do so in your code, but the best time to get the types right is when creating the dataframe.

Comment: Hello @Steven , thank you for the answer. However  the index are not getting converted to dictionary resulting in NAN values. 
So if i remove the "set.index" part, it does get converted to dictionary but without the 'segment_id' and 'cluster. Not sure what i'm doing wrong

Comment: @Vivek: Sorry! I missed pasting a line of code when posting my answer: `answer = pd.Series(index=data.index, data=data).to_dict()`

Comment: @Vivek: You will need to post exactly what you are trying that produces that error.  I think something is being lost in translation.  Also post the first ten or twenty rows or your dataframe.

Comment: I was able to recreate your solution on pandas 0.24.2.. so i think it is something to do with the versions.. your solution works on pandas: 0.24.2 but not on pandas: 0.20.1 I would want it to work on 0.20.1 as that is the organization server version and i will not be able to upgrade it

Comment: @Vivek: What line gives you the error? What is the traceback?

Comment: I get the correct solution with your code on pandas 0.24.2 but with 0.20.1, i get the below. 

(`{'mdse_item_i': {('4454', '5'): nan, ('4161', '5'): nan, ('4295', '5'): nan, ('4144', '5'): nan, ('4123', '5'): nan}, 'predPriceQty': {('4454', '5'): nan, ('4161', '5'): nan, ('4295', '5'): nan, ('4144', '5'): nan, ('4123', '5'): nan}, 'wk': {('4454', '5'): nan, ('4161', '5'): nan, ('4295', '5'): nan, ('4144', '5'): nan, ('4123', '5'): nan}, 'schedule_i': {('4454', '5'): nan, ('4161', '5'): nan, ('4295', '5'): nan, ('4144', '5'): nan, ('4123', '5'): nan}}`)

Comment: I have posted it as another question below
"https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73370380/different-behaviour-in-pandas-0-20-and-0-24-while-creating-a-dictionary-using-la/73371322#73371322"